# How do I overflow a row to have an image on top?

Tags: html, css, image, overflow

**Solved: Seems like I never knew there was a z-index in HTML, thanks again :)**

My Code is this

Basically I tried to put the image over the row but the row is still over my image which I dont want. Basically this is what im working with

[image]

See the skull above? I want to make the skull a link to "index.html" but I cant seem to, the row covers the middle of the skull so only the top and bottom part of the skull is a link (by the way the skull is an image "logo.png") My question is how do I make the image overflow (if that is the word) the row? How do I make the image come out on top of every thing (like layers, how do I make it the top layer?)

This is the code which I did (all I did was put the skull above the row) but it still doesnt work

```
<body class="body1"><img src="/logo.png" class="skull" onmouseenter="hoverlogo(this);" onmouseleave="unhoverlogo(this);" data-href="https://privatelink.com" width="50%" onContextMenu="return false;"/>
    <div class="row" style="margin-top: -45px;">
```

If you guys need anything, please let me know! I will try to respond soon

**PROGRAM IM USING TO CODE IS BOOTSTRAP STUDIO**

Comment: Can you post a working snippet to look into? with the limited content it seems you may have to play around with `z-index`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this

```
<img src="/logo.png" class="skull" onmouseenter="hoverlogo(this);" onmouseleave="unhoverlogo(this);" data-href="https://privatelink.com" width="50%" onContextMenu="return false;" style="z-index:2;"/>
```